# Serving static files throws 404 error Angular SSR

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal

[image]

The screenshot above shows my directory structure of deployed angular ssr project. I.E dist/browser, server and server.js

I am using pm2 and making the angular SSR running as node application,as described in tutorial.

I have used apache proxy to run this node application from apache.

All are working fine. In fact index.html is also being served as described in tutorial, and when I hit the server it renders the html.

The PROBLEM arises when it serves the static content like css,js,images.
It throws 404 error. Attached the screenshot

[image]

As it can be seen 34.x.x.x/abc is actually the proxy path through which the node app runs. It is also serving the index.html. But js, css files throws 404 error.

Below is a snapshot of my server.ts

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
// app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/browser'));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  //res.render('index', { req });
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

where DIST_FOLDER is join(process.cwd(), 'dist')

Ideally it show serve the static content as localhost:4000/styles.x.css etc.

What exactly am I missing ?
Help appreciated

Comment: What is the contents of `dist/browser/`?

Comment: all the necessary files created during build -- index.html, styles.abc33...css, scripts.hg55....js etc

Comment: Can you add your apache vhost.?